# How to use mysql in node with Typescript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

## Background

I'm making a simple website with node and typescript.
I installed [MySQL module](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) to communicate with a database.

## Problem

I'm trying to get data from DB, but I don't know how to determine what type the result should have. For example,

```
const sql = `SELECT metaValue FROM ${this.table} WHERE metaKey = '${key}'`;
const result = await this.pool.query(sql);
console.log(result);
```

in this case, the result is `[ RowDataPacket { metaValue: 'map-79.jpg' } ]`. How can I get `map-79.jpg` from the result? What type the result should be?

Answer (score 2):

it will return Object Array :

```
const sql = `SELECT metaValue FROM ${this.table} WHERE metaKey = '${key}'`;
const result = await this.pool.query(sql);
console.log(result);
result.forEach(row => {
    console.log(row.metaValue)
})
```

Or you Can create array by using `map`

```
let imgArray = result.map(row => { return row.metaValue });
console.log(imgArray);
```

Comment: It returns Query type. I cannot use foreach or map because it is not Array type.

Answer (score 0):

**@Pushpendra Kumar** was right. But we need type guard before using result as Array like below.

```
const sql = `SELECT metaValue FROM ${this.table} WHERE metaKey = '${key}'`;
let rows = await this.pool.query(sql);
if ( Array.isArray(rows) ) {
  return rows[0].metaValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `let records: youDefinedInterface[] = [].slice.call(result, 0);` to cast the Query type to a normal array.